# HTMLUnit cannot find any element after clicking "OK" on an iFrame after Login

Tags: iframe, authentication, htmlunit

I appreceate any little help I can get on the issue I'm facing with HtmlUnit.

What I need to do is to login to my application, go to the home page and get a list of all links, text fields, buttons, etc., on my home page.

I tried coding this, and here's what I can do.

1. I can launch the page, find the login controls, enter user id and password and click Login.
2. The login is successful. At this point, my application displays the home page, which is masked by an iFrame on top, which displays the last login time and other details. There's an OK button on that which I have to click for the underlying home page to be unmasked.
3. I am able to click the OK button as well.

And now here's what I am unable to do.

Once I click OK, the underlying home page is unmasked, yet my HtmlPage object is empty (not null).

Below is my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButton;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButtonInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;

public class HTMLUnitSample {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(false);

        try{
            //Get the first page
            final HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage("http://****:****/****/****");


            //Fill up the login form
            loginPage.getElementById("USERID").setAttribute("value", "****");
            loginPage.getElementById("user_pwd").setAttribute("value","****");

            final HtmlForm loginForm = loginPage.getFormByName("frmLogin");
            HtmlSubmitInput button = loginForm.getInputByName("submit");
            HtmlPage homePage = button.click();
/*          
                System.out.println("Body - " + homePage.getBody().asText());
            System.out.println("No. of Frames in Home Page - " + Inte    ger.toString(homePage.getFrames().size()));
            System.out.println("Total no. of elements on Home Page - " + Integer.toString(homePage.getElementsByTagName("*").size()));*/

            //Click the OK button
            HtmlButtonInput okButton = (HtmlButtonInput)homePage.getElementByName("Ok");
            HtmlPage homePage2 = okButton.click();

            System.out.println(homePage2.asText());

            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The output I get for

```
System.out.println(homePage2.asText());
```

is simply an empty string.

I even tried

```
homePage2.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

but in vain.

What I need is to actually find the elements on the home page after I click OK. 
Please help me. Any little help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have u receive correct page after click submit button ?? Use htmlpage.asXml() to c the html page

Comment: @NiksTyagi In my above code, as soon as I clicked Login button, I go to the home page, where the iFrame with the last log in time message is on top, and the rest of the home page is at the bottom (masked). However, If I use `homePage.asXml()`, I get the markup of only the iFrame and not the rest of the page. When I click OK on the iFrame, the next `homePage2.asXml()` returns an empty string.

Comment: Not knowing the host or the full source code this is very hard to guess as there can be many reasons for this to happen. Now, even if you provide the whole source code, it would probably be very boring to read :)

Comment: @MostyMostacho I understand.. Can you tell me the most common reasons why this could happen?